# Can i view errors and warnings by hovering in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Im used to hovering over an underlined error or warning and then being presented with the error, in xCode i have to click the red circle on the side to view the error. Kind of frustrating.

Is it possible to have it so i can just hover over and have it display?

Answer (score 0):

You can hover over the errors, yes. You'll need to click the error icon on the left, then hover over the new error message on the right.